# How Can I View/Open This File?

Tags: file, viewer

i am trying to open and edit a file that contains some type of custom protection.

file game :gameguard.des

its from lineage2/interlude/system file.

this is not the original version though, it has been modified to block some packets sent to the server.

i've used VS2010 to open it and it shows me the memory and the contents in hex, like viewing computer memory.

here is the file attached. http://www20.zippyshare.com/v/88173717/file.html

so my question is, how can i open it viewing the code in a higher level and edit it? what tools i need to use to do that?

regards, George

Answer (score 0):

This is a Win32 program. You can try to disassemble it, but it's itself a binary file and what the VS2010 is showing you is correct, because it's showing it most probably in HEX format to you.

You need to first figure out which compiler was used to compile this application, then maybe it helps you to refactor the executable.

The fact that you can not directly run this application might be just the extension, maybe if you change the extension to `.exe`, it runs under windows. I don't recommend it though.

Comment: how can i find which compiler was used?
indeed, its not a self executing application, its an extention that works with l2.exe and l2.bin

Comment: here is the l2.exe and l2.bin too and a program i found that decrypts the l2.exe

http://www24.zippyshare.com/v/89337950/file.html